# How to print a recursive string value only once and then count how many times it ocurred?

Tags: java

Hi everyone and thanks for your time. This is a working program for a Finch robot to follow the light.

I need to make it print in the following way:

One can consider 5 basic actions/primitives: forward, left, right, stop (with speed, angle, time, etc. just being parameters associated to these actions). For example, if the 'executed' robot sequence was:

```
forward (speed1), stop (), forward (speed2), left (angle1), right (angle2), forward (speed3), stop ()
```

then the most frequent action in the above example was forward.

Current output e.g.:
forward
forward
forward
forward
forward
forward
left
left
forward

Desired output e.g.:
forward
left
forward

most frequent = forward.

```
import edu.cmu.ri.createlab.terk.robot.finch.Finch;

public class FinchVIVA {


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Finch myf = new Finch();
        int light = 120; //light intensity
        long startInterval = System.currentTimeMillis(); //sets the current time 

        while (true) {
            if (!myf.isObstacle() && myf.getRightLightSensor() > light && myf.getLeftLightSensor() > light) { //if no obstacle and both sensors get enough light
                ledAndWheels(myf, 152, 148); //Finch will go forward (the number values are speeds for each wheel)
                startInterval = System.currentTimeMillis();               
                System.out.println("forward"); //this will print forward EVERY time the if statement is true (I need only once)
            } else if (!myf.isObstacle() && myf.getRightLightSensor() > light && myf.getLeftLightSensor() < light) { //if no obstacle and light sensors right > left
                ledAndWheels(myf, 150, -100); //Finch will turn right
                startInterval = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("right");//this will print right EVERY time the if statement is true (I need only once)
            } else if (!myf.isObstacle() && myf.getRightLightSensor() < light && myf.getLeftLightSensor() > light) { //if no obstacle and light sensors right < left
                ledAndWheels(myf, -100, 1);//Finch will turn right
                startInterval = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("left");//this will print right EVERY time the if statement is true (I need only once)
            } else {
                myf.stopWheels();//this will stio the wheels
                if ((myf.isObstacle()) || (myf.getRightLightSensor() < light && myf.getLeftLightSensor() < light)) {
                    setLed(myf, 255, 0, 0);
                }
                if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startInterval) > 5000) {
                    myf.quit();
                    break;
                }

            }
        }

    }

    public static void setLed(Finch myf, int r, int g, int b) {
        myf.setLED(r, g, b);
    }

    public static void ledAndWheels(Finch myf, int leftWheel, int rightWheel) {
        setLed(myf, 0, 0, 255);
        myf.setWheelVelocities(leftWheel, rightWheel);
        myf.buzz(1500,60);

    }
}
```

Comment: Declare variables int forward, right, left, right..  And in each if condition increment the respective one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import edu.cmu.ri.createlab.terk.robot.finch.Finch;

 public class FinchVIVA {


public static void main(String[] args){
    Finch myf = new Finch();
    int light = 120; //light intensity
    long startInterval = System.currentTimeMillis(); //sets the current time 
    int forward,right, left;
    forward=right=left=0;
    String previousCommand="";
    while (true) {
        if (!myf.isObstacle() && myf.getRightLightSensor() > light && myf.getLeftLightSensor() > light) { //if no obstacle and both sensors get enough light
            ledAndWheels(myf, 152, 148); //Finch will go forward (the number values are speeds for each wheel)
            startInterval = System.currentTimeMillis();               
            if(!previousCommand.equals("forward"))
            {
                  System.out.println("forward");
            } 
             previousCommand="forward";
            forward++;
        } else if (!myf.isObstacle() && myf.getRightLightSensor() > light && myf.getLeftLightSensor() < light) { //if no obstacle and light sensors right > left
            ledAndWheels(myf, 150, -100); //Finch will turn right
            startInterval = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(!previousCommand.equals("right"))
            {
                  System.out.println("right");
            } 
             previousCommand="right";
            right++;
        } else if (!myf.isObstacle() && myf.getRightLightSensor() < light && myf.getLeftLightSensor() > light) { //if no obstacle and light sensors right < left
            ledAndWheels(myf, -100, 1);//Finch will turn right
            startInterval = System.currentTimeMillis();
             if(!previousCommand.equals("left"))
            {
                  System.out.println("left");
            } 
             previousCommand="left";
             left++;
        } else {
            myf.stopWheels();//this will stio the wheels
            if ((myf.isObstacle()) || (myf.getRightLightSensor() < light && myf.getLeftLightSensor() < light)) {
                setLed(myf, 255, 0, 0);
            }
            if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startInterval) > 5000) {
                myf.quit();
                break;
            }


        }
    }

          // If condition to check which of the counter variables(forward, right, left) are greater 
         // Then print which of them was greatest to get your expected result.. 
}

public static void setLed(Finch myf, int r, int g, int b) {
    myf.setLED(r, g, b);
}

public static void ledAndWheels(Finch myf, int leftWheel, int rightWheel) {
    setLed(myf, 0, 0, 255);
    myf.setWheelVelocities(leftWheel, rightWheel);
    myf.buzz(1500,60);

}
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, it does print it only once but it doesn't print it again after. It makes forward, left, right and if forward again it won't print it. But you're close.

Comment: I need it to print something like forward, left, right, left, forward, stop, forward. But instead it prints forward, left, right, stop.